# Pivotal Tracker: why are my epics "done" when they are not "done"?

Tags: pivotaltracker

I can't seem to manually control the state of "done"-ness for my epics, and it is often wrong.

It seems it would only be "done" when all stories are complete. But this not the case. Perhaps its a bug? Perhaps this happens when all stories are complete, but then I add a story later?

[image]

The most frustrating aspect of this is that "done" epics are hidden by default and epics I'm working on keep disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An epic in Pivotal tracker is done when all its stories are either done or in icebox.

Found this from [here](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/blog/using-epics-for-your-project)

> Completing epics
>
> As you complete your stories, epics are considered done (and appear in green) when all prioritized stories in them are accepted. Stories in the icebox are not considered to be “in play” – they’re on ice, and in most cases epics will have stories in the icebox indefinitely. It’s often the case that everything you wanted doesn’t actually get done, yet the feature is perfectly usable. However, as soon as you drag a completed epic’s story from the icebox to the backlog, it will stop being green.
>
> Done epics remain in the Epics panel until the iteration in which stories in them were accepted is over. Then you’ll see “Show x Done Epics” at the top of the epics panel instead.